# Select all occurrences of top K values along each column in a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say I have a NumPy array as follows: My original array is 50K X8.5K size. This is sample

```
array([[ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ],
   [ 1. ,  0.5,  2. ],
   [ 2. ,  3. ,  1. ]])
```

Now what I want is that for each column, only keep top K values (lets take K as 2 here) and re-code others to zero.

So output I am expecting is something like this:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.]])
```

So basically if we see, we kind of sort each column values in descending and then check if each value of that column is not amongst the k- largest values of that column then re-code that value to zero

I tried something like this but it is giving an error

```
for x in range(e.shape[1]):
    e[:,x]=map(np.where(lambda x: x in e[:,x][::-1][:2], x, 0), e[:,x])



     2 
      3 for x in range(e.shape[1]):
----> 4     e[:,x]=map(np.where(lambda x: x in e[:,x][::-1][:2], x, 0), e[:,x])
      5 

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Currently I am also iterating for each column. Any solution which works fast since I have like 50K rows and 8K columns so iterating for each column and then for each column doing map of each value in that column would be time consuming I guess.

Please advise.

Comment: Thanks changed it. Any ans?

Comment: Can't answer (yet) but look at your `map` statement... you're using `x` both in the loop and inside the lambda (conflicting), and you either want to make the first argument of `map` a function (probably a lambda in your case), or remove it.

Comment: I think having x in both is fine.Even if I change the for X to for y it doesn't make diff. I am using the first argument of map as function (where) I can't just use only Lamda function as I need some kind of where function to update the values based on true or false. Lambda gives me the True, False answer, putting that part of where would help me update the values.

Answer (score 1):

With focus on performance for such large arrays, here's a vectorized approach to solve it -

```
K = 2 # Select top K values along each column

# Sort A, store the argsort for later usage
sidx = np.argsort(A,axis=0)
sA = A[sidx,np.arange(A.shape[1])]

# Perform differentiation along rows and look for non-zero differentiations
df = np.diff(sA,axis=0)!=0

# Perform cumulative summation along rows from bottom upwards. 
# Thus, summations < K should give us a mask of valid ones that are to 
# be kept per column. Use this mask to set rest as zeros in sorted array.
mask = (df[::-1].cumsum(0)<K)[::-1]
sA[:-1] *=mask

# Finally revert back to unsorted order by using sorted indices sidx
out = sA[sidx.argsort(0),np.arange(sA.shape[1])]
```

Please note that for more performance boost, `np.argsort` could be replaced by `np.argpartition`.

Sample input, ouput -

```
In [343]: A
Out[343]: 
array([[106, 106, 102],
       [105, 101, 104],
       [106, 107, 101],
       [107, 103, 106],
       [106, 105, 108],
       [106, 104, 105],
       [107, 101, 101],
       [105, 103, 102],
       [104, 102, 106],
       [104, 106, 101]])

In [344]: out
Out[344]: 
array([[106, 106,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [106, 107,   0],
       [107,   0, 106],
       [106,   0, 108],
       [106,   0,   0],
       [107,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 106],
       [  0, 106,   0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there:

```
def rwhere(a, b, p, k):
    if p >= len(b) or p >= k:
        return 0
    else:
        return np.where(a == b[p], b[p], rwhere(a, b, p + 1, k))

def codek(a, k):
    b = a.copy()
    b.sort(0)
    b = b[::-1]
    return rwhere(a, b, 0, k)

codek(a, 2)

array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.]])
```

Comment: I don't understand this.  :-( . Is there something wrong with my Map statement? Should work right?

Comment: This has two function and two where clause with sorting. I have a matrix 50K x 9K. Not sure if sorting is going to be cheap here. Any simpler solution. Thanks for this though.

Comment: I just figured the error in my code. The one liner works fine. Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I just figured out what was the problem in my code. The where clause should be in return condition of lambda function. The below works fine.

```
array([[ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.5,  2. ],
       [ 2. ,  3. ,  1. ]])

e=copy.deepcopy(a)

for y in range(e.shape[1]):
    e[:,y]=map(lambda x: np.where(x in np.sort(a[:,y])[::-1][:2],x, 0), e[:,y])

array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.]])
In [297]:
```

instead of 2 I can keep it as K and should work fine for that too.

Comment: I think sort is fine with me here. Unique will de-dup but might get more values. I think I am looking for top k values duplicate or not duplicate. Thanks for suggestion anyway

Comment: If you have a column `[[3, 3, 2, 2, 1]]` you want to keep the `3`'s *and* the `2`'s right? For K=2. If you use sort, you only keep the `3`'s.